# Backbone's checkbox toggle

Tags: checkbox, backbone.js

I have a checkbox(es) and I am trying to change a bool field of a model when a click event happens.

My HTML checkbox:

```
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox" {{ isChecked }}>
```

My model-view JS:

```
app.SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click .toggle:checkbox': 'toggleChecked'
    },

...

    toggleChecked: function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var selected = $target .is(':checked');
        this.model.save({
            isChecked: selected
        });
    },
})
```

This is the current behavior: 
The checkbox and the value of the field in the model are false too. 
When I click once to the checkbox then the value of the "isChecked" field will be true which is good but it doesn't apply any change on the screen (checkbox looks unchecked). 
When I click to the checkbox second time, then the value of the "isChecked" is still true, and now finally the checkbox looks checked.
When I click to the checkbox third time, then the value of the "isChecked" is false, and the checkbox looks unchecked which is also good.

Maybe there is a better way to connect the fields in backbone but I'm quite new with this framework. Thank you for any help!

Comment: https://codepen.io/dimatabu/pen/vadGNa  
by default everything should work as is.  
but i believe your initial state of checkbox is incorrect if your template receives model attributes as usual
then your input html looks like <input ... true >, because isChecked is true and not "checked"

Comment: Please share a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you @taburetkin, I solved it! I needed to replace the bool values to "" and "checked" in my app-view.js